# How can i decode JSON-like string in cyrillic?

Tags: python, scrapy, cyrillic

I'm trying to create a simple spider in Scrapy that will get all the adverts from a site. The problem is that all the adverts are in cyrillic so i get strings like that:

```
1-\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430
```

Here's spider's code:

```
def parse_advert(self, response):
    x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    advert = AdvertItem()

    advert['title'] = x.select("//h1/text()").extract()
    advert['phone'] = "111111111111"
    advert['text'] = "text text text text text text"
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    open(filename, 'wb').write(str(advert['title']))
```

Is there any way to "translate" that string on the fly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.decode('unicode-escape')`:

```
>>> print r'1-\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430'
1-\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430
>>> print r'1-\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430'.decode('unicode-escape')
1-комнатная квартира
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that it works BUT i wonder if i can do that formatting r operation with a variable. For example here i need to do it with str(advert['title']).

Comment: @Nervosa, Raw string (`r'..'`) was used to avoid tedious backslash-escaping.

Comment: @Nervosa, Do `str(advert['title']).decode('unicode-escape')`.

Comment: @Nervosa, If above code raise UnicodeEncode/DecodeError, do `str(advert['title']).decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: There is no error but there is also no result:


>>> a
'1-\\u043a\\u043e\\u043c\\u043d\\u0430\\u0442\\u043d\\u0430\\u044f \\u043a\\u0432\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u0438\\u0440\\u0430'

>>> a.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')
'1-\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0'

>>> a.decode('unicode-escape')
u'1-\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043a\u0432\u0430\u0
440\u0442\u0438\u0440\u0430'

Comment: @Nervosa, Prepend `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to file 'setting.py' line:

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```